# 2D Array in Java with number manipulation

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

My goal is to

1. Create a 5x5 array and fill it with random integers in the range of 1 to 25.
2. Print this original array
3. Process the array, counting the number of odds, evens, and summing all of the elements     in the array.
4. Print the total odds, evens, and the sum.

Im not sure how to do it and my teacher is very confused and cannot help me. I was wondering if i could get some guidance.

Here is my code:

```
public class Processing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random Random = new Random();
        int[][] Processing = new int[5][5];
        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
            int number = Random.nextInt(25);
            Processing[x] = number;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Processing[i] = new int[10];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How come a teacher be confused about stuff like this ?

Comment: Why you would name your local variable name same as your class name??

Comment: Your for loops aren't nested, and I'm not sure why you did `Processing[i] = new int[10]`.. Please follow [naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367)

Answer (score 2):

Please follow naming conventions for your variables. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java

Anyways, you have to nest your loops as follows:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i ++) {
   for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        yourArray[i][j] = random.nextInt(25);
   }
}
```

`i` is the row number and `j` is the column number, so this would assign values to each element in a row, then move on to the next row.

I'm guessing this is homework so I won't just give away the answer to your other questions, but to set you on the right track, here's how you would print the elements. Again, use two nested loops:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i ++) {
   for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        // print elements in one row in a single line
        System.out.print(yourArray[i][j] + " ");
   }
   System.out.println();  //return to the next line to print next row.
}
```

Comment: Though its syntactically and technically valid in this case, I wouldn't recommend the OP omit curly braces at this stage of their education (until they've mastered loops at least). I fear it would lead them to greater errors on the future.